# What is the canonical way to convert an Array<Byte> to a ByteArray

Tags: arrays, interop, kotlin

If have an Array and want to convert it to a ByteArray, how should I go about it? The following for instance fails:

```
var srcArray = Array<Byte>(10, { 0 })
var tgtArray: ByteArray = srcArray as ByteArray
```

I do realize though that specialized classes such as ByteArray are:

> ... not related to the Array class and are compiled down to Java’s primitive arrays for maximum performance.

So, the fact that my approach fails shouldn't surprise me - but what is the canonical way to make the conversion? Simply iterate through srcArray and populate tgtArray one index at a time - or is there a more elegant solution I'm missing?

Comment: I felt it related to issues of Java interop.

Comment: This is not an issue currently, Kotlin has a stdlib function, see new answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any built-in functions apart from the obvious loop-based approach. But you could define an extension function like this yourself:

```
fun Array<Byte>.toPrimitive(): ByteArray {
    val tgtArray: ByteArray = ByteArray(this.size())

    for (i in this.indices) {
        tgtArray[i] = this[i]
    }

    return tgtArray
}

fun test() {
    val srcArray = Array<Byte>(10, { 0 })

    val tgtArray: ByteArray = srcArray.toPrimitive()
}
```

Comment: This is outdated, there is now a stdlib function.  See other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has this in the stdlib as an extension function `Array<Byte>.toByteArray()`

```
val srcArray = Array<Byte>(10, { 0 })
val tgtArray = srcArray.toByteArray()
```

(*Note:  I changed your `var` to `val` which is more common in Kotlin to use read-only values*)

You will see similar ones for other primitive data types that have array implementations.  You can see them all in the [Kotlin documentation for Array extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html#extension-functions).